# VTK-Animation of several vtkPolyData-Objects

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to make an animation with VTK (C++). All i have are one `vtkPolyData`-Objects for each frame in the animation, stored as `std::vector< vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> >`. What I want is a class with methods like `play()`, `pause()`, `continue()` and `stop()`. So I'm trying to implement that class according to http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/DataAnimationSubclass.
But how can I:

- start the animation: how to pass the first frame into the `vtkProgrammableFilter`?
- continue the animation: how to pass the next frame into the `vtkProgrammableFilter`?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `SetExecuteMethod` on the `vtkProgrammablerFilter` is the argument that gets passed to the callback (in the example, to `AdjustPoints`). You can pass any arbitrary data-structure to it.

```
class MyMetaData
{
std::vector<vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> > PolyDatas;
vtkWeakPointer<vtkProgrammableFilter> Self
};

....

// fill be an instance with defaults.
MyMetaData instance;
instance.Self = programmableFilter.GetPointer();
instance.PolyDatas = ...

// Pass as argument.
programmableFilter->SetExecuteMethod(MyCallback, &instance);

....
```

Don't forget to update MyCallback to expect a pointer of MyMetaData, instead of `vtkProgrammableFilter` as in the case of the original example.